# How to update backbone.model.updated_at after a model.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

When I save a model I want to get the updated_at value from the server.

Currently I do:

```
#Save My model
@model.save()
@listenToOnce @model, "sync", () =>
  #my ruby on rails server returns the asset with the new updated time
  #get the updated time from the server
  @model.fetch()
  @listenToOnce @model, "sync", () => 
    #now my model has the new updated time here.
```

The code on the server side:

```
if anAsset.save!()
      respond_with anAsset
```

It works, but I know I shouldn't be making two trips to the server.  Why doesn't the updated_at time sync with the backbone model.save() call?  Is there a way I can get it with just one trip to the server?

Thanks!

Comment: What JSON is the server responding with when you `@model.save()`? There's no updated `update_at` value in there?

Comment: using a binding.pry I do see that there is a new updated_at value being sent back as part of the anAsset model.

Comment: And is that getting through to the model? Does the new `updated_at` appear in the JSON? Is your Backbone model ignoring it?

Comment: The response is undefined.  Which makes sense as to why it isn't being set.

Comment: Your controller isn't actually sending anything back?

Comment: I guess so.  I added the function success to the model.save options and the second argument is undefined.  The status code I am getting is 204.  So I must have something wrong with my controller.  I tried changing it to respond_with anAsset.to_json  but still have the same problem.

Comment: 204 is, more or less, an "it worked but I'm not sending anything back" response so there's your problem. Why is `respond_with` doing a 204?

Comment: Do you have a [`respond_to :json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to) anywhere? Have you checked the headers that Backbone is sending to your application? Have you tried using `render :json => ...` instead of `respond_with` as a quick hack to help you see what's going on?

Comment: render :json => anAsset works great!  I get the response with the correct updated_at value.  I do not have the repond_to :json line anywhere in the controller.  Should I add that?

Comment: Try adding a `respond_to` and then see if the `respond_with` starts making sense. Almost everything I've been doing for the past few years is JSON front to back so a lot of the magical DWIM format stuff is opaque to me, I just `render :json => ...` 'cuz JSON is all I care about.

Comment: All I care about is the json as well so render :json =>  is a great solution for me.  Feel free to create an answer changing the respon_to to render :json => and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is JSON, then cut to the chase and say so:

```
render :json => anAsset, :status => :ok
```

You can mess around with all the magical `respond_to :json` and `respond_with anAsset` stuff if you want but I find that that stuff just confuses things when you're only speaking JSON.